# Custom method for UIPageviewController datasource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uipageviewcontroller

I want to implement one custom method for uipageviewcontroller datasource that will turn to page at index

something like this

```
- (void) pageViewController:(PageViewController *)pageViewcontroller willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)currentIndex
```

I don't know if this is correct way of implementing custom method for uipageviewcontroller datasource.

Comment: I assume what you're really asking is when will that method be called?

Comment: i implemented this custom method but not sure first if it correct second do i have to declare it in the header file so that it gets executed because it is not called when executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add whatever methods you like to your data source class. Methods that are considered public should also be defined in the header file.

But that's not what you're asking. You're asking: how can I get `UIPageViewController` to call it?

The short version is: you can't.

While your method has a nice, readable signature, to the compiler it's no different to:

```
- (void) pageViewController:(PageViewController *)pageViewcontroller banana:(banana*)banana;
```

There's no way that the controller could be expected to know what to do with it.

I'm afraid, in general, you have to use the methods that are published.

There are *some* exceptions. For example, sometimes there is no delegate method but you can subscribe to a notification. Or maybe there's another delegate to use? In your case I would expect a "will do something" method to be on the delegate rather than the data source.

Comment: You are right willturntopageatindex should be delegate rather than datasource.